# Hello, I am beginner in C++ and have this kind of problem . It gives me multiply errors

Tags: c++

In this code, I try to explain the rules by which a person can get the driving license.. However, it gives me such errors like "expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token", "‘else’ without a previous ‘if’", " expected ‘;’ before ‘cout’", "expected primary-expression before ‘else’
" and "expected ‘)’ before ‘else’"

```
int age = 90;
        int ageAtLastExam = 16;
        bool isNotIntoxicated = true;

        if(age < 16)); //if you are`enter code here` older or equal to 1 and younger than 16, you cannot drive

        cout << "You can't drive" << endl;

        else(age >= 80 && ((age > 100) || ((age - ageAtLastExam) > 5)))  ///if your age is greater than 100, we are not going to allow you to the exam, but if you are older or equal to 80, you will have to take an exam every five years

        cout << "You can't drive" << endl;

     else 

        cout << "You can drive" << endl;
```

Comment: Your question's title is really bad. No one potentially having the same issue as you will find your question by keyword search. Moreover, a good practice is to **exactly** copy-paste error messages (do not change them nor summarize/interpret them).

Comment: You have a syntax error at the end of if() statement; so remove the semicolon and add either namespace std as shown below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last `else` exists without matching `if` block. What you really wanted to have, is a single if-else ladder, which can check various age ranges. Do it like this:

```
    if(age < 16)

        cout << "You can't drive" << endl;

    else if(age >= 80 && ((age > 100) || ((age - ageAtLastExam) > 5))) ) 

        cout << "You can't drive" << endl;

    else //See this else didn't have a previous if 

       cout << "You can drive" << endl;
```

Comment: Thanks, worked :)

Comment: `if(age < 16))` how can that compile ?!? Note the extra `)`